# Reading GCP Spanner database using python

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Hi I started exploring GCP Spanner Database using Python. Testing some basic code, and stumbled on below error, really appreciate if someone can help me ?

Errors I am getting,

```
    return ListValue(values=[_make_value_pb(value) for value in values])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I also, tried keyset = spanner.KeySet(all_=True) which also throwing,

```
    super().__setattr__("_pb", self._meta.pb(**params))
TypeError: Value must be iterable
```

I also tested, snapshot.execute_sql statement, which works fine and give me results.

Code Testing:

```
# Execute a simple SQL statement.
with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
        #results = snapshot.execute_sql("SELECT * From Listings LIMIT 1")
        keyset = spanner.KeySet(keys=(1,23))
        #print (keyset)
        results = snapshot.read(table="Listings",columns=all,keyset=keyset)
```

Comment: I am able to fix the issue that, with columns parameter, which expects explicit column names rather all. I provided explicit column names and it started working.

Comment: still issue, with keyset = spanner.KeySet(keys=(1,23)) though . giving an error        
  ```    return ListValue(values=[_make_value_pb(value) for value in values])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable ```

Comment: Show more of your code. It looks like `values` is an `int`. However, I do not recommend using `values` twice in a compound statement `values=[_make_value_pb(value) for value in values]`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing to `keyset = spanner.KeySet(keys=[(1,23)])` as keys should be a list